# Recursive array parse with nested nodes

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, nodes

I have blackhole in my mind. Im trying to parse array with multilevel nodes. Here's example array:

```
global $array;
$array = [
    '0' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'root 0'
    ],
    '1' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'root 1'
    ],
    '2' => [
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 2,
        'name' => 'root 2'
    ],
    '3' => [
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 3,
        'name' => 'root 3'
    ],
    '4' => [
        'id' => 5,
        'parent' => 3,
        'name' => 'root 4'
    ],
    '5' => [
        'id' => 6,
        'parent' => 2,
        'name' => 'root 2'
    ]
];
```

This should looks after parse like this. Element 3 with parent 3 should have parent 1, because element 2 has parent 2, and its first child.

I trying to get to this using foreach and function:

```
global $new_array;
$new_array = [];

foreach( $array as $item )
{
    if( $item['parent'] == 0 ) {
        $new_array[] = $item; // if parent 0 - clone into new array
        continue;
    }

    //echo $item['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    $new_array[] = check_parent( $item['parent'] ); 

}

print_r($new_array);

function check_parent( $parent )
{
    //echo '- check for parent of ' . $parent . PHP_EOL;
    global $array;
    foreach( $array as $item ) {
        if( $item['id'] == $parent && $item['parent'] == 0 ) {
            //echo '[OK] found root parent id: ' . $item['id'] . PHP_EOL;
            $item['parent'] = $item['id'];
            return $item;
        } else {
            return check_parent( $item['id'] );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm so confused, but I didn't see where I make a mistake. Maybe someone, can help me to see - where's problem. I working on it few hours and for now, I had blackhole in my mind.

Fiddle:
https://implode.io/jHS8m1

Desired output:

```
$new_array = [
    '0' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'root 0'
    ],
    '1' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'root 1'
    ],
    '2' => [
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 2, // this should have after parse parent 1
        'name' => 'root 2'
    ],
    '3' => [
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 3, // this should have after parse parent 1
        'name' => 'root 3'
    ],
    '4' => [
        'id' => 5,
        'parent' => 3, // this should have after parse parent 1
        'name' => 'root 4'
    ],
    '5' => [
        'id' => 6,
        'parent' => 2, // this should have after parse parent 1
        'name' => 'root 2'
    ]
];
```

Thanks !

Comment: You are right. This is what I need to do. This is n-version of this script, some time ago I wrote something similar without any problems, but now - its like i don't know what i'am doing - so I ask for help, because after few hours I stuck and have no idea  how to make this happen. This script doesn't had replace for grandparent, but if returns correct values, replace parent will be a easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following line in your code

```
        $new_array[] = check_parent( $item['parent'] ); // get child
```

with below lines of code.

```
        $temp = check_parent( $item['parent'] ); // get child
        $item['parent'] = $temp['id'];
        $new_array[] = $item;
```

What is happening is that your `check_parent` is returning the `$item`, which happens to be the parent. However, we are only interested in the `id` of this. So we get the `id` and replace the parent it in the original `$item`.

Here is the working [Demo](https://3v4l.org/82iHY)

Answer (score 0):

A bit tardy in my response, but I think it is valuable to provide a refined recursive solution.

My snippet:

1. Modifies by reference
2. Does not leverage a `global` variable declaration
3. Uses just one loop in the custom recursive function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ftCHb))

```
function replaceParent(&$array, $parent = null) {
    foreach ($array as &$item) {
        if ($item['id'] == $parent) {
            if ($item['parent']) {
                return replaceParent($array, $item['parent']);
            } else {
                return $item['id'];
            }
        } elseif ($item['parent']) {
            $item['parent'] = replaceParent($array, $item['parent']);
        }
    }
}

replaceParent($array);
var_export($array);
```

I'll try to explain...

- `id` `1`'s `parent` value of `0` fails both primary conditions, so no recursion/processing is performed on that row of data.
- `id` `2`'s `parent` value of `1` passes the `elseif` condition, so the recursive call goes in search of the row with an `id` of `1`. Finding `id` `1` with a `parent` value of `0` means the `else` branch is satisfied and the `id` value of `1` is passed back through the recursive call to be assigned to `$item['parent']` for the original `id` `2`.
- To process `id` `3` (or deeper), multiple recursive calls occur and all conditions play a role in the search and assignment process.  First the `elseif` leads to the first recursion, then the `if`'s `if` leads to the second recursion, finally the `if`'s `else` passes the root `id`'s value all the way back to the original grandchild.